# DataFrames. Cómo cambiar el margen o alineación en la presentación de la tabla de datos?

Tags: python-3.x

BD

Teniendo un diccionario y presentando sus valores en un `DataFrame`, ¿cómo se puede hacer para cambiar la alineación o el margen del resultado?

Por ejemplo:

si la muestra resultante sale así:

```
A            B
almuerzo     merienda
merienda     merienda
```

y yo lo que quisiera es que salga así:

```
   A            B
almuerzo     merienda
merienda     merienda
```

Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Si utilizas pandas dataframe
prueba utilizar el siguiente paquete:
https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/

Con este puedes hacer lo siguiente por ej:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_two' : [0.0001, 1e-005 , 1e-006, 1e-007],
                   'column_3' : ['ABCD', 'ABCD', 'long string', 'ABCD']})
print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

Dando como resultado:

```
+----+-----------+-------------+
|    |   col_two | column_3    |
|----+-----------+-------------|
|  0 |    0.0001 | ABCD        |
|  1 |    1e-05  | ABCD        |
|  2 |    1e-06  | long string |
|  3 |    1e-07  | ABCD        |
+----+-----------+-------------+
```